# Declare StructType of a Dataframe: column containing org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I have a DataFrame called `df1` with the following scheme:

```
root
 |-- instances: string (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- label: double (nullable = false)
```

Where `features` and `label` were obtained from a `LabeledPoint`. 
I would like to generate a new one DataFrame but modifying the content of the `instances` and the `features`.
In order to do so, I write the following:

```
val schema2 = new StructType()
  .add("instances", "string")
  .add("features", "org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector")  // also I've tried using `vector`
  .add("label", "double")

val schemaEncoder = RowEncoder(schema2)

val df2 = df1.map {
  case Row(inst: String, lp: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector, lbl: Double) => {
    val nInst = modifyInstances(inst)
    val nLP = nInst.split(",")
    Row(nInst, nLP, lbl)
  }
}(schemaEncoder)
```

When I run the code, the problem would be in `.add("features", "org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector")`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to specify its `DataType` as [`org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes.VectorType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes$@VectorType:org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType), like below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes._

val schema2 = new StructType().
  add("instances", StringType).
  add("features", VectorType).
  add("label", DoubleType)
// schema2: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(
//   StructField(instances,StringType,true),
//   StructField(features,org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7,true),
//   StructField(label,DoubleType,true)
// )
```

Comment: That solved the previously mentioned error, but a new one is appeared: `scala.MatchError: ` and it points at the line 3 (creation of the `df2`), any idea?

Comment: I already realized the problem in the new error: `nLP` is an array of String, so I've changed it for this `Vectors.dense(nLP.toArray.map(_.toDouble))` and it works! Thank you!!